# In Woocommerce page, script working only if executed in console

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In a Woocommerce page, I want to hide certain products if they have a badge (a class). I can't simply hide them because if i do, they won't show up as up-sells in the individual products page. So I tried with jQuery, if I type in the console:

```
var liSet = $("body.term-flamboyants-lingerie li.animate");

     if ( $("body.term-flamboyants-lingerie li.animate a").hasClass("setBadge") ){
        liSet.css("display", "none");
     }
```

It works, the products with the badge that are in this particular page are hidden. The problem is that if I write this in my script.js file, it doesn't work. I have more code in "script.js" that is working just fine and it's all wrapped inside a "jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {" I'm a bit at a loss as to why it wouldn't work.

*Edit* A setTimeOut function works, so my code was running before that class was set in the page. Is there a better way?

Comment: try using jQuery everywhere without passing $ to function

Comment: I have tried, it still doesn't work. And a few lines above $ works fine as it's defined in the wrapper.

Comment: try viewing the page source, not inspect element, and see if there are elements with class setBadge. I'm guessing this is just a matter of timings. when your script runs, setBadge is not there yet.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm not sure how to check it or what code to write for this to work. A set time out function works but it's far from ideal...

Comment: find the function that set the class setBadge. There might be a callback or something you can use.

Comment: if you have a link of the page, I might be able to help you look for it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to find out where the class "setBadge" was set as pointed out by Reigel. Then I fixed the issue with:

```
$("a[href*='set']:first-child").addClass('setBadge');


    if ( $("body").hasClass("term-flamboyants-lingerie") ){
        $("a[href*='set']").parent().css("display", "none");
    }
```

I had to hide the parent to also hide prices and other add-ons to the "a" tag.